# Using mapply & rank to create ranking column to each element in a list with R

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand the concept of rank and mapply. I've created a testing code below:

```
V1 <- c(1:4)
V2 <- c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4")
df1 <- data.frame(V1,V2)

V1 <- c(5:8)
V2 <- c("t5", "t6", "t7", "t8")
df2 <- data.frame(V1,V2)

x <- list(df1, df2)
x <- mapply(cbind, x, Rank = rank(-x, ties.method = "first"), SIMPLIFY = F)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the output below, where the ranking is based on V1, with the smallest number being ranked as 1.

```
[[1]]
  V1 V2 Rank
1  1 t1  1
2  2 t2  2
3  3 t3  3
4  4 t4  4

[[2]]
  V1 V2 Rank
1  5 t5  1
2  6 t6  2
3  7 t7  3
4  8 t8  4
```

However, I am confused with my last line of code, with the rank function. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Well, the last line of your code gives me error. `Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator`

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah, yes it gives an invalid argument error. Do you happen to know how I can utilize rank and bind together with mapply, to insert a ranking column? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `transform` with `lapply`

```
lapply(list(df1, df2), transform, Rank= rank(V1, 'first'))
```

Or with `Map`

```
Map(function(x) transform(x, Rank = rank(V1, 'first')), list(df1, df2))
```

---

Or with `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
list(df1, df2) %>%
          map(mutate, Rank = row_number(V1))
#[[1]]
#  V1 V2 Rank
#1  1 t1    1
#2  2 t2    2
#3  3 t3    3
#4  4 t4    4

#[[2]]
#  V1 V2 Rank
#1  5 t5    1
#2  6 t6    2
#3  7 t7    3
#4  8 t8    4
```

#### Update

If we need to `sort` the 'V2' column

```
lapply(list(df1, df2), transform, Rank= rank(V1, 'first'), V2 = sort(V2))
```